# Simple implementation of Kalman filter doesn't respond to changes in input properly

Tags: kalman-filter

I need to filter the heading readings from a GNSS receiver. I was advised to look in to a Kalman filter.
Since I have no background in mathematics or statistics, I had to start from scratch. I found the video's from [Michel van Biezen on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CaCcOwJPytQ) very helpful.

I only need a very basic implementation, for one dimension (if that is the correct term). After the first 6 video's I figured I knew enough for my small application and further videos would require more background than I have.
I wrote a Python class that does what he describes, and when I try it out with his example number series, it matches his solutions for estimate, estimate error and gain. So far so good.

What it comes down to is:
$$KG=E_{est}/(E_{est}+E_{meas})$$
$$EST_t = EST_{t-1} + KG[MEAS - EST_{t-1}]$$
$$E_{{EST}_t} = [1-KG](E_{{EST}_{t-1}})$$

where KG is the gain, EST is the estimate and E the error.

I can post my Python class, but since that seems to correspond to his examples, I think it is rather my reasoning that isn't correct, or the filter isn't what I need.

That works good enough, as long as my heading doesn't change. The filter does not respond to a change in heading as I'd expect (and this is the first thing where I might be wrong).

My reasoning:

- If the heading changes a lot then then I would like the new estimates to respond to that
- (formula 2) To do so, the gain needs to increase so that the new estimate takes more of the difference between the previous estimat and the measurement
- (formula 1) For the gain to increase, the error in the previous estimate should increase (since the error in the measurement is fixed in my application and his example)
- (formula 3) The error estimate only increases when the gain decreases

However, we need the gain to increase...

Or, as I just realize.. even just looking at formula 3, I would think that there is no way for the estimate error increase, since the first part of the multiplication would need to be > 1 which is not possible.

What is wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Depending on how your output changes over time you might need a larger dimension for your state. Maybe a constant velocity or constant acceleration state space model might be a good starting point?

Comment: The situation is that someone will want to take a heading by installing the hardware/system on a fixed platform. However, during installation, the heading will change (possibly dramatically as people might walk around with the receivers switched on). So I need something that would filter decently once installed, but handles large variations as well. As far as I know, Kalman filters are often for data from IMU's, which have a constantly varying output. Maybe that only works with/because of the higher dimensions, but that would be beyond my current (and likely future) capabilities.